# How to approach this type of problem in permutation and combination?

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

### Altitudes

Alice and Bob took a journey to the mountains. They have been climbing
up and down for `N` days and came home extremely tired.

Alice only remembers that they started their journey at an altitude of
`H1` meters and they finished their wandering at an alitude of `H2`
meters. Bob only remembers that every day they changed their altitude
by `A`, `B`, or `C` meters. If their altitude on the `i`th day was `x`,
then their altitude on day `i + 1` can be `x + A`, `x + B`, or `x + C`.

Now, Bob wonders in how many ways they could complete their journey.
Two journeys are considered different if and only if there exist a day
when the altitude that Alice and Bob covered that day during the first
journey differs from the altitude Alice and Bob covered that day during
the second journey.

Bob asks Alice to tell her the number of ways to complete the journey.
Bob needs your help to solve this problem.

### Input format

The first and only line contains 6 integers `N`, `H1`, `H2`, `A`, `B`, `C` that
represents the number of days Alice and Bob have been wandering,
altitude on which they started their journey, altitude on which they
finished their journey, and three possible altitude changes,
respectively.

### Output format

Print the answer modulo `10**9 + 7`.

### Constraints

```
1 <= N <= 10**5
-10**9 <= H1, H2 <= 10**9
-10**9 <= A, B, C <= 10**9
```

### Sample Input

```
2 0 0 1 0 -1
```

### Sample Output

```
3
```

### Explanation

There are only 3 possible journeys-- `(0, 0), (1, -1), (-1, 1)`.

### Note

This problem comes originally from [a hackerearth competition](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/combinatorics/inclusion-exclusion/practice-problems/algorithm/climbing-b0536d6a/), now closed. The explanation for the sample input and output has been corrected.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any error messages.

Comment: You also should show your problem as text in your question rather than as a linked graphic. That makes it possible for us to copy-and-paste into our editors. It also makes it much easier for others to search for your question and the resulting answers, so this helps others in the future.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Well Thanks for the warm welcome. I just wanted to ask what should we add to the details when we don't how to approach the math behind the question (I mean if we have no idea how to proceed with thought process )

Comment: You should at least show us some of your attempts at the problem, even if none of those attempts were successful. You could explain just why this problem is so difficult for you. This would show us that you are not just throwing your homework problem on us. Many people do try to do that--show us that you are not one of those people. Typing out your problem as text would help but you need more than that.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for telling me about it. I will make sure it won't happen again in future.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I know it's not up to the mark but now can i get any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in Python 3.

The question can be simplified from its 6 input parameters to only 4 parameters. There is no need for the beginning and ending altitudes--the difference of the two is enough. Also, we can change the daily altitude changes A, B, and C and get the same answer if we make a corresponding change to the total altitude change. For example, if we add 1 to each of A, B, and C, we could add N to the altitude change: 1 additional meter each day over N days means N additional meters total. We can "normalize" our daily altitude changes by sorting them so A is the smallest, then subtract A from each of the altitude changes and subtract N * A from the total altitude change. This means we now need to add a bunch of 0's and two other values (let's call them D and E). D is not larger than E.

We now have an easier problem: take N values, each of which is 0, D, or E, so they sum to a particular total (let's say H). This is the same at using up to N numbers equaling D or E, with the rest zeros.

We can use mathematics, in particular [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), to see if this is possible. Some more mathematics can find all the ways of doing this. Once we know how many 0's, D's, and E's, we can use [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) to find how many ways these values can be rearranged. Total all these up and we have the answer.

This code finds the total number of ways to complete the journey, and takes it modulo 10**9 + 7 only at the very end. This is possible since Python uses large integers. The largest result I found in my testing is for the input values `100000 0 100000 0 1 2` which results in a number with 47,710 digits before taking the modulus. This takes a little over 8 seconds on my machine.

This code is a little longer than necessary, since I made some of the routines more general than necessary for this problem. I did this so I can use them in other problems. I used many comments for clarity.

```
# Combinatorial routines -----------------------------------------------


def comb(n, k):
    """Compute the number of ways to choose k elements out of a pile of
    n, ignoring the order of the elements. This is also called
    combinations, or the binomial coefficient of n over k.
    """
    if k < 0 or k > n:
        return 0
    result = 1
    for i in range(min(k, n - k)):
        result = result * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return result


def multcoeff(*args):
    """Return the multinomial coefficient
    (n1 + n2 + ...)! / n1! / n2! / ..."""
    if not args:  # no parameters
        return 1
    # Find and store the index of the largest parameter so we can skip
    #   it (for efficiency)
    skipndx = args.index(max(args))
    newargs = args[:skipndx] + args[skipndx + 1:]

    result = 1
    num = args[skipndx] + 1  # a factor in the numerator
    for n in newargs:
        for den in range(1, n + 1):  # a factor in the denominator
            result = result * num // den
            num += 1
    return result


def new_multcoeff(prev_multcoeff, x, y, z, ag, bg):
    """Given a multinomial coefficient prev_multcoeff = 
    multcoeff(x-bg, y+ag, z+(bg-ag)), calculate multcoeff(x, y, z)).

    NOTES:  1.  This uses bg multiplications and bg divisions,
                faster than doing multcoeff from scratch.
    """
    result = prev_multcoeff
    for d in range(1, ag + 1):
        result *= y + d
    for d in range(1, bg - ag + 1):
        result *= z + d
    for d in range(bg):
        result //= x - d
    return result


# Number theory routines -----------------------------------------------


def bezout(a, b):
    """For integers a and b, find an integral solution to
    a*x + b*y = gcd(a, b).

    RETURNS:    (x, y, gcd)

    NOTES:  1.  This routine uses the convergents of the continued
                fraction expansion of b / a, so it will be slightly
                faster if a <= b, i.e. the parameters are sorted.
            2.  This routine ensures the gcd is nonnegative.
            3.  If a and/or b is zero, the corresponding x or y
                will also be zero.
            4.  This routine is named after Bezout's identity, which
                guarantees the existences of the solution x, y.
    """
    if not a:
        return (0, (b > 0) - (b < 0), abs(b))  # 2nd is sign(b)
    p1, p = 0, 1  # numerators of the two previous convergents
    q1, q = 1, 0  # denominators of the two previous convergents
    negate_y = True  # flag if negate y=q (True) or x=p (False)
    quotient, remainder = divmod(b, a)
    while remainder:
        b, a = a, remainder
        p, p1 = p * quotient + p1, p
        q, q1 = q * quotient + q1, q
        negate_y = not negate_y
        quotient, remainder = divmod(b, a)
    if a < 0:
        p, q, a = -p, -q, -a  # ensure the gcd is nonnegative
    return (p, -q, a) if negate_y else (-p, q, a)


def byzantine_bball(a, b, s):
    """For nonnegative integers a, b, s, return information about
    integer solutions x, y to a*x + b*y = s. This is
    equivalent to finding a multiset containing only a and b that
    sums to s. The name comes from getting a given basketball score
    given scores for shots and free throws in a hypothetical game of
    "byzantine basketball."

    RETURNS:    None if there is no solution, or an 8-tuple containing
                x   the smallest possible nonnegative integer value of
                    x.
                y   the value of y corresponding to the smallest
                    possible integral value of x. If this is negative,
                    there is no solution for nonnegative x, y.
                g   the greatest common divisor (gcd) of a, b.
                u   the found solution to a*u + b*v = g
                v   "   "
                ag  a // g, or zero if g=0
                bg  b // g, or zero if g=0
                sg  s // g, or zero if g=0

    NOTES:  1.  If a and b are not both zero and one solution x, y is
                returned, then all integer solutions are given by
                x + t * bg, y - t * ag for any integer t.
            2.  This routine is slightly optimized for a <= b. In that
                case, the solution returned also has the smallest sum
                x + y among positive integer solutions.

    """
    # Handle edge cases of zero parameter(s).
    if 0 == a == b:  # the only score possible from 0, 0 is 0
        return (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) if s == 0 else None
    if a == 0:
        sb = s // b
        return (0, sb, b, 0, 1, 0, 1, sb) if s % b == 0 else None
    if b == 0:
        sa = s // a
        return (sa, 0, a, 1, 0, 1, 0, sa) if s % a == 0 else None
    # Find if the score is possible, ignoring the signs of x and y.
    u, v, g = bezout(a, b)
    if s % g:
        return None  # only multiples of the gcd are possible scores
    # Find one way to get the score, ignoring the signs of x and y.
    ag, bg, sg = a // g, b // g, s // g  # we now have ag*u + bg*v = 1
    x, y = sg * u, sg * v  # we now have a*x + b*y = s
    # Find the solution where x is nonnegative and as small as possible.
    t = x // bg  # Python rounds toward minus infinity--what we want
    x, y = x - t * bg, y + t * ag
    # Return the information
    return (x, y, g, u, v, ag, bg, sg)


# Routines for this puzzle ---------------------------------------------


def altitude_reduced(n, h, d, e):
    """Return the number of distinct n-tuples containing only the
    values 0, d, and e that sum to h. Assume that all these
    numbers are integers and that 0 <= d <= e.
    """
    # Handle some impossible special cases
    if n < 0 or h < 0:
        return 0
    # Handle some other simple cases with zero values
    if n == 0:
        return 0 if h else 1
    if 0 == d == e:  # all step values are zero
        return 0 if h else 1
    if 0 == d or d == e:  # e is the only non-zero step value
        # If possible, return # of tuples with proper # of e's, the rest 0's
        return 0 if h % e else comb(n, h // e)
    # Handle the main case 0 < d < e
    # --Try to get the solution with the fewest possible non-zero days:
    #   x d's and y e's and the rest zeros: all solutions are given by
    #   x + t * bg, y - t * ag
    solutions_info = byzantine_bball(d, e, h)
    if not solutions_info:
        return 0  # no way at all to get h from  d, e
    x, y, _, _, _, ag, bg, _ = solutions_info
    # --Loop over all solutions with nonnegative x, y, small enough x + y
    result = 0
    while y >= 0 and x + y <= n:  # at most n non-zero days
        # Find multcoeff(x, y, n - x - y), in a faster way
        if result == 0:  # 1st time through loop: no prev coeff available
            amultcoeff = multcoeff(x, y, n - x - y)
        else:  # use previous multinomial coefficient
            amultcoeff = new_multcoeff(amultcoeff, x, y, n - x - y, ag, bg)
        result += amultcoeff
        x, y = x + bg, y - ag  # x+y increases by bg-ag >= 0
    return result


def altitudes(input_str=None):
    # Get the input
    if input_str is None:
        input_str = input('Numbers N H1 H2 A B C? ')
    # input_str = '100000 0 100000 0 1 2'  # replace with prev line for input
    n, h1, h2, a, b, c = map(int, input_str.strip().split())

    # Reduce the number of parameters by normalizing the values
    h_diff = h2 - h1  # net altitude change
    a, b, c = sorted((a, b, c))  # a is now the smallest
    h, d, e = h_diff - n * a, b - a, c - a  # reduce a to zero

    # Solve the reduced problem
    print(altitude_reduced(n, h, d, e) % (10**9 + 7))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    altitudes()
```

Here are some of my test routines for the main problem. These are suitable for pytest.

```
# Testing, some with pytest ---------------------------------------------------

import itertools  # for testing
import collections  # for testing


def brute(n, h, d, e):
    """Do alt_reduced with brute force."""
    return sum(1 for v in itertools.product({0, d, e}, repeat=n)
               if sum(v) == h)


def brute_count(n, d, e):
    """Count achieved heights with brute force."""
    if n < 0:
        return collections.Counter()
    return collections.Counter(
        sum(v) for v in itertools.product({0, d, e}, repeat=n)
    )


def test_impossible():
    assert altitude_reduced(0, 6, 1, 2) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(-1, 6, 1, 2) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(3, -1, 1, 2) == 0


def test_simple():
    assert altitude_reduced(1, 0, 0, 0) == 1
    assert altitude_reduced(1, 1, 0, 0) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(1, -1, 0, 0) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(1, 1, 0, 1) == 1
    assert altitude_reduced(1, 1, 1, 1) == 1
    assert altitude_reduced(1, 2, 0, 1) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(1, 2, 1, 1) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(2, 4, 0, 3) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(2, 4, 3, 3) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(2, 4, 0, 2) == 1
    assert altitude_reduced(2, 4, 2, 2) == 1
    assert altitude_reduced(3, 4, 0, 2) == 3
    assert altitude_reduced(3, 4, 2, 2) == 3
    assert altitude_reduced(4, 4, 0, 2) == 6
    assert altitude_reduced(4, 4, 2, 2) == 6
    assert altitude_reduced(2, 6, 0, 2) == 0
    assert altitude_reduced(2, 6, 2, 2) == 0


def test_main():
    N = 12
    maxcnt = 0
    for n in range(-1, N):
        for d in range(N):  # must have 0 <= d
            for e in range(d, N):  # must have d <= e
                counts = brute_count(n, d, e)
                for h, cnt in counts.items():
                    if cnt == 25653:
                        print(n, h, d, e, cnt)
                    maxcnt = max(maxcnt, cnt)
                    assert cnt == altitude_reduced(n, h, d, e)
    print(maxcnt)  # got 25653 for N = 12, (n, h, d, e) = (11, 11, 1, 2) etc.
```